# Parallel SURF and SIFT computing

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How can I speed up SURF and SIFT operation? I know that I should use TBB but what function of TBB should I use?? Maybe parallel_for?
I got code:
int minHessian = 400;

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;
detector.detect( img_object, keypoints_object );
detector.detect( img_scene, keypoints_scene );
//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;
extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
extractor.compute( img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );
//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#surf-operator) says that the SURF uses TBB inside, so you should build OpenCV with TBB support.

Comment: So if I use TBB I dont speedup it??

Comment: 1. build openCV with TBB support to probably use block-parallelism inside of the `.detect` function automatically, which might bring the best speed-up. 2. you could use task-parallelism to compute each two of your `.detect` and `.compute` lines in parallel. This only makes sense if you have free ressources, so you should test that first (after building openCV with TBB you probably dont have any cpu ressources left there).